# Linear Algebra - Understanding how to determine if a transformation is linear

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

I'm new to linear transformations in linear algebra and I can't quite understand how to find out if a transformation is linear.

Any help would be much appreciated!

a) $T:\mathbb{R}^2 \to\mathbb{R}^4$ defined by $T(x, y) = (xy, 0,x, y)$

b) $T:\mathbb R^3 \to\mathbb R$ defined by $T(x, y, z) = x - 3y +2z$

How do find out if they are a linear transformation?

Comment: Are you familiar with how linear transformations are defined? Do the proposed transformations conform to the definitions?

Comment: There's something wrong with domain and codomain in a).

Comment: A linear transformation must satisfy $T(ax+by) = aT(x) + bT(y)$ for any $a,b$ scalar and $x,y$ in domain of T

Comment: There's still something wrong with domain and codomain in a).

Comment: @alex This is why I'm confused. Thats what the question asks..

Comment: T must reach $\mathbb{R}^4$ not R^2

Comment: Whether it is linear or not, if the domain is $\mathbb R^3$ then $T$ has to have $3$ variables,

Comment: And if its codomain is $\mathbb R^2$ then the value of $T$ must have $2$ components.

Comment: So your map is actually $\mathbb R^2\rightarrow\mathbb R^4$.

Answer (score 3):

a) Consider $T(2,2) + T(3,3) = (4,0,2,2) + (9,0,3,3) = (13,0,5,5)$

This is not equal to $T(5,5)$ and thus, T is not a linear transformation

b) Consider $T(ax+by)$ where $a,b,$ are scalars and $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3), y = (y_1,y_2,y_3) $

Then:
$T(ax+by) = ax_1+by_1-3ax_2-3by_2+2ax_3+2ay_3$
$=a(x_1-3x_2+2x_3)+b(y_1-3y_2+2y_3)$
$=aT(x)+bT(y)$

Thus, T is a linear transformation

Comment: I'd say "it is not equal to $T(5,5)$".

Comment: @alex that you for the suggestion, i edited the answer